# Spring Data JPA Sort + Specification generate extra outer join causing unexpected query results

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a simple case with 2 entities, moreover, the parent is optional for the child:

```
class Parent {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String type;
}

class Child {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "child_parents", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"))
    private Parent parent;
}
```

I have a query retrieving a list of children:

```
Specification<Child> specification = new Specification<>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Child> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
         List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
         // some another restrictions go here
         // ...
         predicates.add(
             criteriaBuilder.or(
                  parentJoin.get(Parent_.type).in(supportedTypes()),
                  criteriaBuilder.isNull(parentJoin.get(Parent_.id))
             )
        );
        Join<Child, Parent> parentJoin = root.join(Child_.parent, JoinType.LEFT);
        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
    }
};

repository.findAll(specification, pageable);
```

The code above works pretty well. The generated SQL looks also good:

```
select * from child
left outer join child_parents ...
left outer join parent ...
where ...
limit ?, ?
```

Now I have a requirement to sort children by the name of the parent. Children with a parent should come first, children without a parent should come after them.

The code looks like:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 10, Sort.by(Sort.Order.asc("parent.name").with(NULLS_LAST)));
Page<Child> page = repository.findAll(specification, pageable);
```

But unfortunately, the code aboce causes 2 huge problems:
1) It adds 2 weird joins:

```
select * from child
left outer join child_parents ...
left outer join parent ...
left outer join child_parents c_p_2 ... # one here
cross join parent p_2 ... # another
where ...
p_2.id = c_p_2.parent_id
order by case when p_2.name is null then 1 else 0 end, p_2.name asc
limit ?, ?
```

Semantically the extra joins are equal to an inner join. They restrict the result list to children with parents only despite I need all children

2) The count returned in `Page` doesn't correlate with a real number of returned entities. It happens because Spring removes orders clauses before generating a count query. Orders removal removes extra joins as well - that's why the count doesn't correlate with a real number of entities

So the count query looks as follows:

```
select count(*) from child
left outer join child_parents ...
left outer join parent ...
where ...
```

Could anybody advise what's wrong with my approach? For me, it looks like a bug in Spring but wanted to ask for advice first.

Comment: Why should this be a bug in Spring? it only delegates to your JPA provider. The joins are generated by JPA and are needed to provide the `nulls_last` case. What you could try is adding an explicit alias for the `join` in the predicate, which might result in re-use of an existing join instead of adding additional ones.

Comment: I'm saying this is a Spring bug because Spring JPA is responsible for querying the count of total entities, converting Spring Sort to JPA sort, etc. At least I expect the proper number of total entities, but since Spring removes all orders from the count queries (along with extra joins) it might cause unexpected results.

All magic happens in `QueryUtils` which is a Spring class. This class detects if there are any joins and creates additional joins when needed. So I assume the bug is there

Comment: I've already tried to add aliases, but it didn't help. Spring Sort doesn't detect aliases properly and says "there is no such property in Child class" when I'm trying to reference an alias while creating `Sort` object

Comment: Removing the order shouldn't impact the query results, only the ordering. It would be interesting to detect what/why is the extra joins being added, as they already exist. IMHO the count query is the correct one (as it includes all the childs you want) and the ordered and paged one isn't. Do you use paging as well as ordering or only the ordering part of the Page? I would also be interested in seing the actual predicates you are building, your current code includes a single one and some stuff related to criteria builder, but I cannot see how that ties together.

Comment: I've updated my answer by adding actual predicates

Comment: And yes, I use both ordering and pagination parts of `Page`

Comment: and it only goes haywire with the ordering? What happens if you remove the `nullsLast` part does it work then?

Comment: Just tried and the result is that `nullsLast` affects nothing. I tried `native` and got the same extra joins

Comment: What do you mean with native?

Comment: `NullHanling` type. `Sort.Order.asc("parent.name").with(NATIVE)`

Comment: I was wondering what `Sort.Order.asc("parent.name")` would do so without anything. I'm trying to figure out where the alias detection goes wrong.

Comment: I understood. `NATIVE` is a default type under the hood, even if nothing specified

Comment: I wonder if this is due to the fact that you create the predicates outside of the `Specification` which might lead to some weird double `Root` and `CriteriaBuilder` which lead to a non-match in the ordering. You could try and move the logic inside the `Specification` and reuse the `Root` etc. from there instead of creating your own from the `EntityManager`.

Comment: Actually my original code builds predicates inside specification. Just provided wrong example. I've already updated the question to move the creation of predicate inside the `Specification`

Comment: @MykolaYashchenko: I've just stumbled upon the exact same problem. Did you happen to find a solution for that? I've decided to go with distinct query which worked in my case, but I wonder if there is another solution?

Comment: @Archie instead of using Spring pagination, I used a JPA (against CriteriaQuery) one. It helped, but it doesn't look like a good solution. Unfortunately, I haven't managed to find a better solution.